# How can I make "Developer" menu always visible in iOS settings?

Tags: ios, xcode

With Xcode loaded, and my device connected, I see the Developer menu item in settings:

[image]

It stays there when I disconnect Xcode, but after rebooting the device (and also perhaps after a certain amount of time even without reboot - days/hours? Not 100% sure on this one) the menu item disappears, which is annoying.

Is there a way to either prevent the menu item disappearing, or force it to always show without connecting Xcode?

Comment: Close Settings app from background and re-open it, it will bring 'Developer' menu in list..!!

Comment: This doesn't work for me on iOS 9.1. Developer menu still not there... Try rebooting your device and you'll see that the menu item disappears and can't be brought back...